# How to create a custom Circle() property in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, uiview, computed-properties

I would like to create a custom circle that I can reuse. (Essentially, I would have one spot to edit the circle's properties. So in the future, it will be easier to update my circle's properties without having to edit them in every location they are used.)

I have attempted to do this by using a computed property like so:

```
var circleView: Circle {
    let customCircle = Circle()
        .fill(circleBackgroundColor)
        .frame(height: circleHeight)
    return customCircle as! Circle
}

var body: some View {
    ZStack() {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cellCornerRadius)
            .fill(cellBackgroundColor)
            .frame(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
        VStack() {
            circleView
            Text($firstName.wrappedValue)
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(titleColor)
        }
    }
}
```

However, strangely, Xcode just crashes.. No errors, no reasons explaining why... just crash. Won't show any preview...

Edit: Oh, and I'm fairly positive the crash has to do with force casting as Circle... but that's the only way I can think of this to work, hence the reason for posting the question.

Any ideas?

Comment: replace `var circleView: Circle` with `var circleView: some View`

Comment: I don't see any option to make this comment the answer. My apologies.